# How to get response from 2nd azure static web app when called from the 1st static web app?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, azure-static-web-app

Currently I am trying to capture the user's credentials from login to 1st app and trying to send it while calling 2nd static web app.

```
getUserInfo()
.then(async (clientPrincipal) =>  {
console.log(clientPrincipal);
const response = await fetch(url_of_2nd_azure_static_web_app, {
headers: {
'X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME': clientPrincipal.userDetails,
'X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID': clientPrincipal.userId,
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, OPTIONS',
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
}
});
}, []);
```

I am not sure if it is even possible ? This is image of the error that I am facing

[image]

I have already tried adding global headers to my staticwebapp.config.json  & I am still getting CORS Error.

```
'globalHeaders': {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, OPTIONS"
},
```

Comment: The CORS Error in Azure portal url after deployment (or) in local

Comment: I am getting the same error in both the cases.

Comment: could provide details about Authorization used in the first app